# Determine the convergence of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to prove the next recursively defined sequence is convergent and find its limit.

$a_1 = \frac14$

$a_{n+1} = \frac {{a_{n}}^2} 6(n+5) \int_0^{\frac 3n} e^{-2{x^2}}dx$

Assuming that it is convergent, I proved that the limit is $0$ or $6$. I would like to determine that it is $0$ showing that the sequence is decreasing but I couldn´t do that. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have $a_{n+1} \leq 3a_n^{2}$ for all $n$ (because $e^{-2x^{2}} \leq 1$ and  $n+5 \leq 6n$) .  From this it follows that $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ are all less than $1$. Now $a_{n+1} \leq \frac {a_n^{2}} 6 (n+5) \frac  3 n\leq a_n^{2}$ if $n \geq 5$. It follows that $a_n \leq 1$ for all $n$ and that $a_{n+1} \leq a_n^{2} \leq a_n$ for $n \geq 5$. Hence $(a_n)$ is eventually decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

If $n \in \mathbb N$, then there is $t_n \in [0, 3/n]$ such that

$$\int_0^{\frac 3n} e^{-2{x^2}}dx=\frac{3}{n}e^{-2t_n^2}.$$

This gives

$$a_{n+1} = \frac {{a_{n}}^2}{6} \cdot\frac{3(n+5)}{n}e^{-2t_n^2}.$$

If $a_n \to 6$, then , since $t_n \to 0$,

$$6=\frac {6^2}{6} \cdot 3 \cdot 1=18,$$

a contradiction.